# LOAD DATA INFILE and user access

Tags: mysql

I am trying insert data from file into mysql table, I am use for this `LOAD DATA INFILE`, this is my php code

```
sql = " HERE LOAD DATA INFILE QUERY ...";
$sth = $db->prepare( $sql ); 
$sth->execute();

var_dump( $sth->errorInfo() );
```

Data is not loaded and errorInfo() shows that `Access denied for user 'blabla'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But this user, which I connect to DB, has ALL PRIVILEGES.

Why this happened? Where I am wrong?

Comment: pls show us the rights that this user has

Comment: can u able to load data using  mysql shell ?

Answer (score 2):

Try granting rights for files :

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO user@localhost
```

You can read more on this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file)

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` returns that `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB_NAME.* TO 'blabla'@'localhost'`

Comment: `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO blabla@localhost` this query also returns error: `Access denied for user 'blabla'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: try executing this query using mysql shell logged on as root

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan's answer rightly states, you need to grant the FILE privilege to the user who wants to load data from external files. This privilege needs to be granted by root or a user with appropriate grant privileges.

Note, that the FILE privilege is a **global** privilege. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/

When you use the command `grant all privileges on <dbname>.* to <user>@<host>;` you are granting **database** privileges. Hence the file privilege will not be included in the grant statement.

After granting privileges, whether global or database or any level, it is always a good idea to execute command `flush privileges;` to ensure the changes are applied.

IMPORTANT: there is also a difference between the commands `load data infile` and `load data local infile`. As stated in the MariaDB documentation:

> When you execute the LOAD DATA INFILE statement, MariaDB Server
> attempts to read the input file from its own file system. In contrast,
> when you execute the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement, the client
> attempts to read the input file from its file system, and it sends the
> contents of the input file to the MariaDB Server. This allows you to
> load files from the client's local file system into the database.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/

If you are attempting to load a CSV file from your home directory you must use `load data local infile`.